# Spawning a thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a folder structure with many files, some of these files are text, html, photos, I would like to iterate through the files in main thread, and everytime the file is a photo, I would like to have it drawn or (something) on another worker thread.

- This seems to launch a new thread each time a file is a photo in the for loop? Is there a way I can launch the thread once, and just pass it the file name when it is a photo?
- Another question, Lets say I have an arrayList objectin thread 1, I would like to fill it up in Thread 2, and remove objects from it in Thread 1, I know it needs to be synchronized, I tried the example but the arraylist seems to be empty in thread 1 after I filled it in thread 2, What am I missing?

Pseudo code:

Thread 1:

```
Class Main{
    List list = new ArrayList();
    void main(){
        for(file f : files) {
           if(file is PHOTO_TYPE)
             new Thread(new ImageRunnable(file)).start();
        }
    }

     //This causes exception because list.size is still empty
     for(int i=0; i<10,i++)
       list.remove(i);
    }
```

Thread 2 Class:

```
class ImageRunnable extends Main implements Runnable() {
    File file;
    ImageRunnable(File f){ 
        this.file = f;
    }

    void run(){
       drawPhoto(file);
    }
    void drawPhoto(File f){
        for(int i=0; i<100,i++)
           list.add(i);
         //something that can take long time
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This seems to launch a new thread each time a file is a photo in the for loop? Is there a way I can launch the thread once, and just pass it the file name when it is a photo?

I'd use an `ExecutorService` instead of launching threads directly.  Then you can have a single thread handling the thread-pool and you submit as many files as you want to the thread-pool.  See the [java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html).

```
// this starts a thread-pool with 1 thread
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
for (File f : files) {
    // you can submit many files but only 1 thread will process them
    threadPool.submit(new ImageRunnable(file));
}
// once we have submitted all jobs to the thread pool, it should be shutdown
threadPool.shutdown();
```

> Let's say I have an arrayList objectin thread 1, I would like to fill it up in Thread 2, and remove objects from it in Thread 1, I know it needs to be synchronized, I tried the example but the arraylist seems to be empty in thread 1 after I filled it in thread 2, What am I missing?

Completely different question which is harder to answer without the specific code.  You need to make sure that you are synchronizing both around the updates *and* the reading of the list.  You might want to consider switching to using a `BlockingQueue` which takes care of the locking for you.  You then can have one thread `add(...)` to the queue and the other one calls `take()`.

Comment: Java Concurrency in Practice also has an example very very similar to OP's, where it scans HTML for other links and loads them in a separate thread.  Consider buying the book.

Comment: @Gray +1 by great answer + fast fingers

Comment: @Gray, I was not aware of ExecutorService, I will read up on it and is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!